# Cannot remove list item from ul todo list

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I tried to remove the list item inside ul with `querySelectorAll` and remove going through each li element. Where is the mistake please, and how is it fixed?

```
<div class='container'>
         <h1> New todo list</h1>
         <form>
                  <input type= 'text' id='item'             
      required>
          <ul> </ul>
      <button id='button'> clear all</
       button>
</div>
```

Here's the code:

```
var form = 
         document.querySelector('form')
 var ul = document.querySelector('ul')
 var button = 
     document.querySelector(#button)
  var input = 
      document.querySelector('item')

   var liMaker = text => {
         var li = 
           document.createElement('li')
           li.textContent = text
           ul.insertBefore(li, 
                      ul.childNodes[0])
            button.onclick = remove
       }
      form.addEventListener('submit', 
             function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
           liMaker(input.value)
            input.value = ' '
       })
       function remove(e){
        Array.from(
           document.querySelectorAll('
            li')).forEach(item => 
            e.target.item.remove())
        }
```

Comment: `e.target.item.remove()` makes no sense The target (aka what you clicked) has no item

Comment: @epascarello can you elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your code a little and added a new button to keep the functionality separate. I think this is the kind of functionality you were after if I understood your question correctly.

```
<div class='container'>
  <h1> New todo list</h1>
  <form>
    <input type='text' id='item' required>
    <ul id="myList"></ul>
    <button id='button'>add</button>
  </form>
  <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')
var ul = document.querySelector('ul')
var button = document.querySelector('#button');
var input = document.querySelector('#item');
var clear = document.querySelector('#clear');

 var liMaker = text => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = text;
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0])
 }

 form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   liMaker(input.value)
   input.value = '';
 });

clear.addEventListener('click', remove);

 function remove(){
  saveToDos();
      while (ul.firstChild) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
      }
    }

function saveToDos() {
  var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    savedToDos.push(items[i].innerHTML);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('savedValues', savedToDos);
}
```

Here is a link to a working pen: https://codepen.io/caeking/pen/RzyKmV

Comment: can you add localstorage so it doesnt get item lost when reload.

Comment: Just added a bit of code to the bottom that will save to local storage upon clearing the list :)

Comment: @CaeSeas can you make it todolist remain even when reload the page and clear button make localstorage clear. what is savedToDos  is it array or storage variable.

Comment: @daneillone It is an array of the to dos that is then saved as an array to local storage. You would need to check the local storage value on page load and if it exists then loop through the array and add them to the li elements.